# How to convert list [a, b, c] to python slice index[:a, :b :c]?

Tags: python, arrays, list

For example, I'm having a group of multi-dimension arrays. I want to write a method to specify the size of the slice for this array such as:

```
slice = data[:a, :b, :c]
```

Because I could only get a list of [a, b, c]. I want to know how can I convert this list to slice index. Or is there a way to connect the list with slice index so as to operate this array as:

```
list = [a, b, c]
slice = data[list]
```

Any reply would be appreciated.

Comment: Or you using numpy or native python lists?

Comment: I am using numpy list

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [slice()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) function.

```
my_list = [a, b, c]
my_slices = tuple(slice(x) for x in my_list)
my_slice = data[my_slices]
```

(I updated the variable names to avoid shadowing the builtins by mistake.)

`slice(x)` is equivalent to the slice `:x`, and `slice(x, y, z)` is `x:y:z`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I tried your method. But it returned a "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable" error.

Comment: Try it with a clean run. I think you overwrote `slice` in your session. Never use names of built-in functions as own variable or function names.

Comment: Did you use 'tuple' or 'slice' as a variable name? If so, you should rename your variables to avoid clashing with builtin names.